# Passing mean and standard deviation into dnorm() using Rcpp Sugar

Tags: r, rcpp

I am converting some R code to Rcpp code and need to calculate the likelihood for a vector of observations given a vector of means and vector of standard deviations.  If I assume the means are 0 and the standard deviations 1, I can write this function (running this requires the 'inline' and 'Rcpp' packages to be loaded),

```
dtest1 = cxxfunction(signature( x = "numeric"),
                      'Rcpp::NumericVector xx(x);
                       return::wrap(dnorm(xx, 0.0, 1.0));', 
                       plugin='Rcpp')
```

and the result is as expected.

```
> dtest1(1:3) 
[1] 0.241970725 0.053990967 0.004431848
```

However, if I try to make a function

```
dtest2 = cxxfunction(signature( x = "numeric", y="numeric", z="numeric" ),
                  'Rcpp::NumericVector xx(x);
                   Rcpp::NumericVector yy(y);
                   Rcpp::NumericVector zz(z);
                   return::wrap(dnorm(xx, yy, zz));',
                   plugin='Rcpp')
```

which would allow me to pass in different means and standard deviations results in an error, shown below.  Is there a way to make the function I am trying to make, or I do need to program the normal density manually?

**Error**

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) :   
    Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! file31c82bff9d7c.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* file31c82bff9d7c(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)’:
file31c82bff9d7c.cpp:33:53: error: no matching function for call to 
     ‘dnorm4(Rcpp::NumericVector&, Rcpp::NumericVector&, Rcpp::NumericVector&)’
file31c82bff9d7c.cpp:33:53: note: candidates are:
/home/chris/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/stats/norm.h:106:1: 
     note: template<int RTYPE, bool NA, class T> Rcpp::stats::D0<RTYPE, NA, T> Rcpp::dnorm4(const Rcpp::VectorBase<RTYPE, NA, VECTOR>&, bool)
/home/chris/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/stats/norm.h:107:1: 
     note: template<int RTYPE, bool NA, class T> Rcpp::stats::D1<RTYPE, NA, T> Rcpp::dnorm4(const Rcpp::VectorBase<RTYPE, NA, VECTOR>&, double, bool)
/home/chris/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/stats/norm.h:108:1: 
     note: template<int RTYPE, bool NA, class T> Rcpp::stats::D2<RTYPE, NA, T> Rcpp::dnorm4(const Rcpp::VectorBase<RTYPE, NA,
In addition: Warning message:
running command '/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB file31c82bff9d7c.cpp 2> file31c82bff9d7c.cpp.err.txt' had status 1
```

Comment: The error message says you used the `dnorm4` function. (However, I get the same sort of error on a Mac.)

Comment: @Dwin I don't understand why the error says that I used the dnorm4 function because I copied the code above from my computer and that was the error message.  I also am having a hard time understanding exactly how Rcpp sugar works, so that is part of the problem I suppose.

Comment: I don't understand it either, but I can also produce the same error with this code: `dtest = cxxfunction(signature( x = "numeric" ),
'Rcpp::NumericVector xx(x);
 return::wrap(dnorm(xx, 0, 1));',
 plugin='Rcpp')`  The only difference is that the mean and sd arguments are not in decimal form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sugar `dnorm` is only vectorized in terms of the first argument.

To simplify (it is slightly more involved, but we don't need to concern ourselves with this yet here), the call

```
dnorm(xx, 0.0, 1.0)
```

uses the overload

```
NumericVector dnorm( NumericVector, double, double )
```

And the second call tries to use something like

```
NumericVector dnorm( NumericVector, NumericVector, NumericVector )
```

which is not implemented. We could implement it, it would have to go high enough in our priority list.

In the meantime, it is easy enough to write a small wrapper, like (this does not handle argument lengths, etc ...) :

```
NumericVector my_dnorm( NumericVector x, NumericVector means, NumericVector sds){
    int n = x.size() ;
    NumericVector res(n) ;
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++) res[i] = R::dnorm( x[i], means[i], sds[i] ) ;
    return res ;
}
```

Comment: So why does calling with `dnorm(xx, 1,0)` throw the same error?

Comment: I'm guessing the compiler looks for an overload using `int` as second and third arguments, and gets confused with the one in the R api.

Comment: Maybe you need to pass a bool to dnorm and set log equal to false as the `dnorm` function in R has this extra option