# Using dnorm with RcppArmadillo

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

From `R`, I'm trying to run `sourceCpp` on this file:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace arma; 
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec dnormLog(vec x, vec means, vec sds) {
    int n = x.size();
    vec res(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res[i] = log(dnorm(x[i], means[i], sds[i]));
    }
return res;
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18154414/2019896) to see where I got the function from.  This throws the error:

`no matching function for call to 'dnorm4'`

Which is the exact error I was hoping to prevent by using the loop, since the referenced answer mentions that `dnorm` is only vectorized with respect to its first argument.  I fear the answer is obvious, but I've tried adding `R::` before the `dnorm`, tried using `NumericVector` instead of `vec`, without using `log()` in front. No luck.  However, adding `R::` before `dnorm` does produce a separate error:

```
too few arguments to function call, expected 4, have 3; did you mean '::dnorm4'?
```

Which is *not* fixed by replacing `dnorm` above with `R::dnorm4`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two nice teachable moments here:

1. Pay attention to namespaces. If in doubt, don't go global.
2. Check the headers for the actual definitions. You missed the fourth argument in the *scalar* version `R::dnorm()`.

Here is a repaired version, included is a second variant you may find interesting:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec dnormLog(arma::vec x, arma::vec means, arma::vec sds) {
  int n = x.size();
  arma::vec res(n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    res[i] = std::log(R::dnorm(x[i], means[i], sds[i], FALSE));
  }
  return res;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec dnormLog2(arma::vec x, arma::vec means, arma::vec sds) {
  int n = x.size();
  arma::vec res(n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    res[i] = R::dnorm(x[i], means[i], sds[i], TRUE);
  }
  return res;
}


/*** R
dnormLog( c(0.1,0.2,0.3), rep(0.0, 3), rep(1.0, 3))
dnormLog2(c(0.1,0.2,0.3), rep(0.0, 3), rep(1.0, 3))
*/
```

When we source this, both return the same result *because the R API allows us to ask for logarithms to be taken*.

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/dnorm.cpp")

R> dnormLog( c(0.1,0.2,0.3), rep(0.0, 3), rep(1.0, 3))
          [,1]
[1,] -0.923939
[2,] -0.938939
[3,] -0.963939

R> dnormLog2(c(0.1,0.2,0.3), rep(0.0, 3), rep(1.0, 3))
          [,1]
[1,] -0.923939
[2,] -0.938939
[3,] -0.963939
R>
```

Comment: Dead on with the remark about namespaces. `using namespace [...]` causes a lot more problems than it solves in my experience.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  For the 4th argument issue, I was initially trying to pass `log = TRUE` but I should have passed `TRUE`.  I now remember seeing the complications associated with passing named arguments in the documentation.  Thanks for a very informative answer.